React Swiper starting at the end when setting width auto
I am using React Swiper and reading their documentations, i test the Centered Slide true and auto module. It's working but my swiper is starting at the end
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

import './styles.css';

// import required modules
import { Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
const images = [
  "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5683aff9a12f443fdcd7b3a0/1530627570442-WLIWNUHZB7R5FFY8VMAU/emmadaviesphotography-5815.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/b/b1/20210811082420%21Portrait_placeholder.png",
  "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5683aff9a12f443fdcd7b3a0/1530627570442-WLIWNUHZB7R5FFY8VMAU/emmadaviesphotography-5815.jpg",
  
  
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={'auto'}
        centeredSlides={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        modules={[Pagination]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
       
        {images.map(img => (
          <SwiperSlide>
          <img src={img} style={{ width: '100%', objectFit: 'contain'}} />
       </SwiperSlide>
        
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}

The Css style
#app {
  height: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: auto !important;
}

I expect it to start at the start, i set the swiper-slide to width: auto because i want them to have same heights and keep their original aspect rations. It is working but my problem is it is starting at the end.
.swiper-slide {
  width: auto !important;
}

